# How to display name and POST value with MVC TextBox helper?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I have this `TextBox`. The model alsway include a `UserName`.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserId, new { @class = "floatLeft" })
```

I want to dipslay the `UserName`, but post the `UserId` to the `ModelBinder` when posting. Is there a way to tell the `TextBox` what to display and what to use when passing data back to Server?

Comment: Is the username editable?

Comment: No. The TextBox is Readonly actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest adding a hidden input and setting it's value to the UserId if you really need this value in the view/form but are not needing it to be editable.

```
<input type="hidden" name="UserId" value="@Model.UserId" />
```

I wrote this manually because with POSTs, I have had mixed issues with using @Html.HiddenFor() under certain conditions.

I did forget to change the textbox:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName, new { @class = "floatLeft" })
```

Comment: And have textbox with UserName instead right? @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName, new { @class = "floatLeft" })

Comment: Added to answer. Forgot that part. :)

Comment: I rather want to use the ViewBag for the UserName, to keep the model clear. Can I do like this? @Html.TextBox("UserName", (string)ViewBag.UserName, new { @class = "floatLeft" })

Comment: The first parameter "UserName" can be anything right? It's just a id that I will never use i think.

Comment: I would make it part of the model. I mean, you are using a class for the model anyways and UserName is already defined as a property? ViewBag is good for miscellaneous things, not so much for important data.

Comment: The testing took a while because this example is simplified to hold focus.
The solution you provided, with a hidden input to hold the witch only role is to hold the id until it's getting passed to the Server worked. thanks.